# Running Python Backend Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, image-processing, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to using firebase so I was looking to see if it was possible to call a python script in firebase to manipulate an image.

I have already written a python program that takes an input image and processes it and returns a new image. I would like to extend this where a mobile or web app could send a user-provided image, to the database, the python program would run and the app would show the processed image.

I assume that a REST API could handle this but my question is if I could run the python script over the cloud. I know firebase has a cloud run function but I have never touched it. Please let me know if there are any resources for this or any alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Although Firebase Functions can be written only in [JS or TS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) they are part of Google Cloud Function. If you create the function in Firebase you will see it as well in [Functions in Google Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/functions).

So it's practically the same feature, however GCP gives you possibility to write cloud functions in many languages (currently 7, I think). Among them you can use [Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-python)
in version 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 (currently in beta).

You can use GCP GUI to write the functions or use [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart#functions_quickstart_describe-python) (`gcloud functions deploy`) to create the function. Nice examples are in mentioned documentation.

Additionally the Cloud Function has nice [choice of triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling) including Firebase related.